Rust dll with Python using CDLL
i am trying to use a dll that was build with rust, in python, i can import the module and even run the function , but for some reason i get an error regarding the size of the data that i don't understand:
here is the rust code:
/// Encrypts the input plain text with the 32 bytes key and IV.
#[no_mangle]
fn encrypt_ige(plain: &[u8], key: &[u8], iv: &[u8]) ->  Vec<u8> {
    let mut key_array = [0; 32];

    key_array.copy_from_slice(key);

    let mut iv_array = [0; 32];

    iv_array.copy_from_slice(iv);

    let cipher = grammers_crypto::encrypt_ige(plain, &key_array, &iv_array);
    return cipher;

}

/// Decrypts the input cipher text with the 32 bytes key and IV.
#[no_mangle]
fn decrypt_ige(cipher: &[u8], key: &[u8], iv: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut key_array = [0; 32];
    
    key_array.copy_from_slice(key);

    let mut iv_array = [0; 32];

    iv_array.copy_from_slice(iv);

    let plain = grammers_crypto::decrypt_ige(cipher, &key_array, &iv_array);
    return plain;

}

/// Factorizes the pair of primes ``pq`` into ``(p, q)``.
#[no_mangle]
fn factorize_pq_pair(pq: u64) -> (u64, u64) {
    grammers_crypto::factorize::factorize(pq)
}

and the python code is:
from ctypes import *


def decrypt_ige(cipher_text, key, iv):
    
    
    cryptg=CDLL('cryptg.dll')
    decrpted=cryptg.decrypt_ige(cipher_text,key,iv)
    return decrpted

but when i run the code i get:
"thread '' panicked at src\lib.rs:22:15:
source slice length (400212022800) does not match destination slice length (32)"
i checked and the key and iv length is 32.
i also tried:
from ctypes import *


def decrypt_ige(cipher_text, key, iv):
    
    
    raw_ubytes = (ctypes.c_ubyte * len(cipher_text)).from_buffer_copy(cipher_text)
        raw_ubytes2 = (ctypes.c_ubyte * len(key)).from_buffer_copy(key)
        raw_ubytes3 = (ctypes.c_ubyte * len(iv)).from_buffer_copy(iv)
        
    cryptg=CDLL('cryptg.dll')
    decrpted=cryptg.decrypt_ige(raw_ubytes,raw_ubytes2,raw_ubytes3)
    return decrpted

but got basically the same thing:
"thread '' panicked at src\lib.rs:22:15:
source slice length (400212022800) does not match destination slice length (32)"
not sure what am i doing wrong here.
any help would help.
thank you.

A function exported to Python needs to be extern "C", and it cannot take/return slices, tuples, Vecs, or many other types.

thanks for your help,
so is there any way i can make it work?
@Chayim Friedman

Why not use PyO3 or maturin to bring the Rust module into Python rather than going through CDLL/ctypes?

&[u8] is not C safe, you'd probably need to change signatures or better: create wrappers.
